# Can using the Documents List API cause files to appear on the change list?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

My application is currently using the Document List API to track file and metadata changes using the Changelist.  When we find a file has changed, we grab the metadata, the acl information, and the actual file.  Lately we've found that we are getting a number a percentage of files that continually show up in the changelist every time we check.

After a bit of investigating, there is very little metadata that is changing in the file.
Here are examples from two different files that continually show up in the changelists.

Is there anyway I can avoid seeing these files over and over again?  I have partially optimized to not download the files again, but it is still taking extra quite a bit of overhead to weed out false-positives from the changelist.  Does anyone know if updating my app to use the Drive API will fix this issue?

Here is an example of what I'm seeing:

File 1 - Through the Documents List API
Initial Info

> entry:etag=\""CkcaSU1LASt7ImBk"\"
>
> id:...feeds/id/spreadsheet%3A0AgVqS9FfzZOCdGhZSVZ4UEtyT2tmRnZsR3lGNFBrVWc
>
> ```
>  published:2010-12-13T01:58:22.467Z
>
>  updated:2010-12-13T02:03:22.269Z
> ```
>
> ...
>
> link:rel=\"thumbnail\" type=\"image/jpeg\" href=...?id=0AgVqS9FfzZOCdGhZSVZ4UEtyT2tmRnZsR3lGNFBrVWc&v=1&s=AMedNnoAAAAAUQHGlnP_b5jppjlFLN9OHRY5VSP2KZNR&sz=s220\"
>
> ...
>
> /entry

Next Time I looked at the changelist

> entry etag=\""CkUFR0sIQyt7ImBk"\"
>         id:...feeds/id/spreadsheet%3A0AgVqS9FfzZOCdGhZSVZ4UEtyT2tmRnZsR3lGNFBrVWc
>
> ```
>  published:2010-12-13T01:58:22.467Z
>
>  updated:2010-12-13T02:03:22.269Z
> ```
>
> ...
>      link:rel=\"thumbnail\" type=\"image/jpeg\" href=\"...?id=0AgVqS9FfzZOCdGhZSVZ4UEtyT2tmRnZsR3lGNFBrVWc&v=1&s=AMedNnoAAAAAUQMH4STQC7QSN1CJivPIl0U5KvMD8eKe&sz=s220\"
>
> ...
>
> /entry

The only differences are the etag, updated time, and thumbnail image.  The file itself did not change at all.

File 2 - This info I grabbed using the APIs explorer (using the DriveAPI 2 changes.get)

> {
>
> ```
>  "kind": "drive#change",
>
> "id": "21012",
>
>  "fileId": "0AgVqS9FfzZOCdGQyQUNjWkF0alVpNGd0WXNLMnpNU2c",
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>  "thumbnailLink": ".../feeds/vt?gd=true&id=0AgVqS9FfzZOCdGQyQUNjWkF0alVpNGd0WXNLMnpNU2c&v=1&s=AMedNnoAAAAAUQlhSo3rF73K5WnN7E0qSR0uMhWEqM-t&sz=s220",
> ```
>
> ...
>
> }

Ran through grabbing changes from the Documents List API, then checked the changelist again.

> {
>
> ```
> "kind": "drive#change",
>
> "id": "21013",
>
> "fileId": "0AgVqS9FfzZOCdGQyQUNjWkF0alVpNGd0WXNLMnpNU2c",
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>  "thumbnailLink": ".../feeds/vt?gd=true&id=0AgVqS9FfzZOCdGQyQUNjWkF0alVpNGd0WXNLMnpNU2c&v=1&s=AMedNnoAAAAAUQlh69m8ZG_MzNujmmu80HN9XJ2jpG61&sz=s220",
> ```
>
> ...
>
> }

In this case, the thumbnail link had again changed, and there was no longer a change with id 21012.